# How to implement two actions on public void onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

I'm developing a simple android app that uses webview to open a remote URL, I use the android studio nav. drawer template witch has already in the `MainActivity.java` this piece of code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this piece of code to enable the go back button when a user explores some pages of the remote website

```
if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
    mWebView.goBack();
```

As I tested I can't have two times the  `public void onBackPressed()` in my `MainActivity.java`

Any thoughts on how can I make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an if-else branch to the existing if-else. E.g

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
       mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

this way, if the drawer is open, if you hit the back button it will be closed. If it is closed you will be calling `mWebView.goBack();` 'till`canGoBack()` returns true

Comment: Yes that made it work, I appreciate your help Blackbelt! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
                return;
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Wukash